# Management of users sharepoint server 2016 passwords

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am new in sharepoint, I am setting up a GED with sharepoint. My problem is at the level of the users: I can not determine how the end users can change their password store in active directory. If someone has leads, I'm interested.
Also if it is possible to authenticate users from an LDAP directory without going through passwords.
Thank you in advance.